# TypeError: "x.write" is not a function

Tags: typeerror

```
PanelRenderer.rendererBody = function (oR, oItem) {
        const sText= oItem.getText();
        if (sText) {
            oR.write("<h1>");
            oR.write("</h1>");
            oR.writeBack(sText);

        }
    };
PanelRenderer.render = function (oR, oItem) {
        this.start(oR, oItem);
        this.rendererBody(oR, oItem);
        this.end(oR);
    };
```

I cannot reproduce this error so I would like to ask any possible reasons of this type error
This error is in the compiled version.

What I thought was undefined, so put ?. in front of write function like oR?.write( )
But not sure cause i cannot reproduce it.

And how can I fix if it cannot be reproduced?

Comment: "I cannot reproduce this error" — So how do you know it exists at all?

Comment: "any possible reasons of this type error" — We can't see what value is passed to `oR` when the `render` function is called. Whatever that value is, it is something that doesn't have a `write` property. We have no idea why you wrote code that thinks it does have a `write` property. You haven't provided enough context. Please read [ask].

Comment: "how can I fix if" — You don't fix error messages. You use error messages to identify problems, then you fix the problem. There's not enough information in your question to get from the error message to the problem.

Comment: Sorry for limited info. I'll look it over.

Comment: There is no trace of TypeScript in the posted code. Please tag the question correctly to maximize the chance to get a useful answer.

Comment: Okay, sure I will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see that message randomly, at (at least) one point in your code something is passed as first parameter (ie as `oR`) to your `render` (and therefore also `rendererBody`) function, that doesn't have the correct type, and thus does not have a `write` function.

Typescript can only assure compile time type safety. Ie, when the data at runtime differs from the expected data, there is nothing typescript can do about it.

Fixing might be hard, if it's not (reliably) reproducible. You can only check where your `render` (or `rendererBody`) is called, and see where the data you pass into that function comes from and if it by any chance might not be, what you expect it to be.